Como mostrar al usuario un mensaje con error de integridad de datos (UNIQUE) con Spring Boot?
Actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicación con Spring Boot y Thymeleaf (es mi primer desarrollo), y no he logrado que el manejo de excepciones capture la excepción java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException y enviarla al front para mostrar en pantalla al usuario.
El método en la clase de servicio es el siguiente:
@Transactional
public SaveResult actualizar(Equipo equipo) throws DataConstraintViolationException { 
    SaveResult saveResult = new SaveResult(false, null);
    try {
        equipoDao.save(equipo);
        saveResult.setMessage("Los datos del equipo se han guardado exitosamente");
        saveResult.setSuccess(true);
   return saveResult;
    } catch (DataConstraintViolationException ex) {
        saveResult.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        saveResult.setSuccess(false);
        return saveResult;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Se produjo una excepción: ");
        saveResult.setMessage(extractExceptionMessage(ex));
        saveResult.setSuccess(false);
        return saveResult;
    }
    
}

Si dejo el código anterior como está, me muestra el siguiente error: "exception DataConstraintViolationException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement"
y si en el bloque try agrego la línea: "throw new DataConstraintViolationException("mensaje de error");
entonces siempre me envía al bloque catch DataConstraintViolationException.
Hay alguna forma de controlar mediante un if si el método save() tuvo éxito para que en caso contrario capture la excepción y se ejecute solo en ese caso el código del bloque catch?
Todos los tutoriales que encuentro los hacen con ejecutar una consulta para devolver un NOT_FOUND, pero ninguno con la ejecución del método save().
De antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

"si en el bloque try agrego la línea: "throw new DataConstraintViolationException("mensaje de error");
entonces siempre me envía al bloque catch DataConstraintViolationException" -> Ya no, claro. Y si añades un if (true) explode() siempre explotará. Si estás siempre tirando la misma excepción, qué esperas que haga el catch?? Por qué no usas lo que devuelve el método save para determinar si se grabó o no?? Supongo que algo devolverá. Porque no puedes intentar atrapar una excepción que no se tira en tu método, tal como te indica el error. Y de todas maneras, no es buena práctica usarlas así

Tal como indica @Benito-B en su comentario, habría que ver qué tipo de excepción lanza el método save del objeto equipoDao (si es que lanza alguna excepción) y es esa la excepción que debes controlar en este caso. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y agregas más detalles para poder ayudarte. Por ejemplo, podrías añadir la declaración del método save. Saludos
